# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to filter the JSON results of tickets from open to closed and in progress, the json data is returned correctly from the api and saved in `totalTicketsDataMain` variable. But whenever I try to filter the data the varible to store `openTicketsData` throws and error on mozilla

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: x is null
> getTicketsData/</this.openTicketsData
> ```

and on google chrome throws the error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
    at ticketlist.component.ts:98
```

the line number 98

```
this.openTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => (x.status === "Open" || x.status === "In Progress")); //line 98
```

am not sure what I am missing or am doing wrong this is my TicketlistComponent

```
openTicketsData: Ticket[];
  totalTicketsDataMain: Ticket[];

status = "Open";
 async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
       await this.getTicketsData();
  }

 async getTicketsData(): Promise<void> {
    this.totalTicketsDataMain = await this.ticketService.getTickets(this.currentProjectId);
    if (this.teamId && this.eaId && this.householdId) {
      this.totalTicketsDataMain = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => x.eaId == this.eaId && x.householdId == this.householdId && x.teamId == this.teamId && x.status == this.status);
    }

    if (this.totalTicketsDataMain) {
      this.openTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => (x.status === "Open" || x.status === "In Progress")); //line 98
      this.inProgressTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => (x.status === "In Progress"));
      this.closedTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => (x.status === "Closed"));
      let user =  this.userSessionService.getSession('usersession') as UserSession;
      this.assaignedToMeTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => x.assignedTo == user.emailId);
      this.createdByMeTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter( x=> x.createdBy == user.emailId);
    }

    if (this.teamId == undefined  || this.eaId == undefined || this.householdId == undefined) {
      this.totalTicketsData = this.totalTicketsDataMain.filter(x => x.status == "Open" || x.status == "In Progress");
    }


  }
```

get tickets service function

```
async getTickets(projectId: string): Promise<Ticket[]> {
        try {
            const url = ServiceConstants.apiUrl + `/tickets/getticketlist?projectId=${projectId}`;
            let response = await this.httpService.get(url, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).toPromise();
            return response as Ticket[];
        } catch (error) {
            this.handleError(error);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That because `x` is null and null does not have `status` property you have to debug and find out why x becames null in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first two of your if conditions do not follow, your `this.totalTicketsDataMain` will remain `null`. Trying to get `this.totalTicketsData` would then be impossible. Also, if all conditions do not follow, no status is set as open.

Comment: Hi @Rumjhum Singru  I dont understand what you mean

Comment: this.totalTicketsDataMain is null, that is none of your if conditions have been satisfied.@arriff

Comment: but when I do a console log it has data,  `this.totalTicketsDataMain = await this.ticketService.getTickets(this.currentProjectId);
    console.log("data is thre ",this.totalTicketsDataMain)`, it prints data

Comment: Do you mind showing your console log on line 98, just before the filter.

Comment: have shared, the data is available

Comment: Trying putting another filter on x like .filter(x => x.filter(x1 =>x1.status....)